# How can a <div> have a width greater than it's max-width?

Tags: css

I've got a `<div>` with:

```
display: block;
max-width: 150px;
position: static;
overflow: hidden;
```

However, the `<div>` has a width of `530px`, which is well in excess of the `max-width` I specified, and I can't figure out why.

When I inspect the `<div>` in Chrome, it very clearly shows the `max-width` being applied (and not being trumped by any other rules), but at the same time in the "Computed" tab it clearly shows the `530px` width.

I'm not asking for help debugging my particular situation though.  Rather, I'm just trying to understand how, under any circumstances whatsoever, a block-level element with `overflow: hdden` can have a width that exceeds its `max-width`.

Clearly I'm not fully understanding how `max-width` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could please provide the whole code, I am fairly certain that I'll be able to help. Don't worry, I won't plagiarize your work. This question has got me interested.

But if I had to make a wild guess, here are a few reasons how that could be:
1. When you use width: 200%, and max-width: 100px; well, things like that tend to create problems.
2. Is display: block, really necessary in that code? Div is by default a block element.
3. You can use JS to overwrite any style and might end up not knowing what caused the increase just by inspection.
4. You might have misplaced a closing tag, i.e.

Here's a clearer and shorter version of how max-width works:
You want a div that increases in width with content, however, you do not want it to exceed a certain width. So, you write the following code:
width: 100%;
max-width: 150px;
In order to properly use it, you may have to nest a div inside that 100% width div to get the correct effect. It's really difficult to tell without the whole code. However, this might be another issue too:

Now, if you place the above div inside a container div with 200px width, the 100% width property will take over and it might exceed the max-width too.

Comment: Well it turned out to be a combination of me forgetting how `max-width` works on `block` elements (@see Wolfram Rong's answer) and something else I just discovered that's so dumb I'm ashamed to admit it: I also had a `min-width` that I wasn't noticing, and the `min-width` exceeded the `max-width`.  Given such garbage CSS, I can't really blame the browser for exceeding my `max-width` :-)

Answer (score 5):

For anyone coming upon this later, the collective answer is that the following circumstances can cause a `<div>`'s `width` to exceed it's `max-width`:

1. If the element has a `display:block` and has any room to grow it will ignore it's `max-width` (@see Wolfram Rong's answer)
2. When the `width` and `max-width` conflict (eg. width: 200%, and max-width: 100px); @see DKaikster's answer (for a similar issue with `min-width` see #4 below)
3. If the `<div>` (or any related element) is not closed properly the browser will do it's best to handle the bad HTML, and the result may cause weird conditions; again @see DKaikster's answer
4. This is the one that hit me, and it's basically another version of #2: if the `min-width` of the `<div>` exceeds the `max-width` the browser may (Chrome certainly does) ignore the `max-width` in favor of the `min-width` (@see my comment to DKalkster's answer)

If anyone comes across any other ways to produce this confusing situation please comment, and I'll happily update this answer so that someday we can have a single comprehensive answer to this surprisingly challenging question.

Answer (score 4):

I am new to front-end development. 

I also want to mention that padding is not counted to the width and it could be possible that in an inner `<div>`, the `width` is specified to `100%`, but the `<div>` with `padding` could look like that the `<div>` exceeds the `width`.

Adding

```
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        box-sizing:border-box;
```

could solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The `max-width` property only specifies the content width. If the element is `display: block`, it will **always** take up 100% of the available space. The remaining space will be filled up with a margin instead.

```
|--------------- 100% ------------------|
_________________________________________
|    150px    |      100% - 150px       |
|    Content  | Margin added by browser |
|_____________|_________________________|
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhh!  I guess I float my `<div>`s (or `display: inline-block`) so often I forgot how they behave without the float.  Thanks!